# C# XmlDocument: Dynamically retrieve xml childnode attribute names

Tags: c#

I have the following sample XML-file:

```
<response location='location1'>
    <meas name='mt1'>14</meas>
    <meas name='mt2'>23</meas>
    <meas name='mt3'>65</meas>
    <meas name='mt4'>31</meas>
    <meas name='mt6'>32</meas>
</response>
```

I can retrieve the inner values, but I am trying to also dynamically retrieve "name" value of each childnode, ie:
'mt1', 'mt2', etc.

How would one go about doing this in XmlDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the XML structure provided and an `XmlDocument`, query for the `meas` nodes and then get the attribute values:

```cs
static string xml = @"<response location='location1'>
    <meas name='mt1'>14</meas>
    <meas name='mt2'>23</meas>
    <meas name='mt3'>65</meas>
    <meas name='mt4'>31</meas>
    <meas name='mt6'>32</meas>
</response>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//response/meas");
foreach (XmlElement e in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetAttribute("name"));
}
```

Result:

```
mt1
mt2
mt3
mt4
mt6
```

Alternatively, directly query the attributes:

```cs
var attrs = doc.SelectNodes("//response/meas/@name");
foreach (XmlAttribute e in attrs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```